# Slide div to top of divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I slide a div to the top of a page, if the div is number 3 out of 5 divs and it should go to the top of the divs and push the other divs under the div that is slided to the top.

The closest result i've found, is this: http://biostall.com/demos/swap-and-reorder-divs-smoothly-using-jquery/

The only problem with that is, that it is swapping position with another div, where I want it to slide to the top of all the divs

Comment: There are many variables that could make your job easier or more difficult. EG: fixed size DIVs would make it easier. Do you need animation? If not you can store your DIV and append it on top of the page.

Comment: Is this (http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) what are you looking for?

Comment: Why can't you use the same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/sNaFG/)

**html**

```
Click on a box
<img />
<img />
<img />
<img />
<img />
```

**js/jQ**

```
var y = 100;
$('img').each(function () {
    $(this).css("top", y + "px");
    $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(0,90," + y + ")");
    y += 55;
});


$('img').click(function (e) {

    $(e.target).animate({
        top: "100"
    });

    $(e.target).siblings().each(function () {
        if ($(this).position().top < $(e.target).position().top) {
            $(this).animate({
                top: "+=55"
            });
        }
    });

});
```

**css**

```
img {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```